# Obfuscation of email and phone using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm creating a new website, so I am thinking about how to protect my email address and phone number against crawlers, I actually mean [email harvesters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address_harvesting) (most of which I suppose don't have JavaScript enabled, but I don't have any proof of it). What I do now is definitely [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) or [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) (I might be confusing the two terms), as **I want the email address to be *normally visible* and *clickable* by the user**.

I started with resurrecting my 10+ years old code and editing it a little. The basics remain the same as 10+ years ago when I first coded this principle.

My question for Code Review SE - as I already posted **Is this a valid option?** in Security SE [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211626/82570) - is rather clear. Primarily, I am interested in a review of this piece of code:

---

### HTML part

```html
<span id="m_link">test [a.t] example [d.o.t] com</span>
<span id="t_link">+444 444 6[eight]6 6[eight][eight]</span>
```

### JavaScript part

```js
function fix_m_link()
{
    var item1 = '@'; var item2 = '.'; var m_clear_text = 'test' + item1 + 'example' + item2 + 'com';
    document.getElementById('m_link').innerHTML = '<a href="mai' + 'lto:' + m_clear_text + '">' + m_clear_text + '</a>';
}

function fix_t_link()
{
    var item8 = '8'; var t_with_spaces = '444 6' + item8 + '6 6' + item8 + item8; var t = t_with_spaces.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    document.getElementById('t_link').innerHTML = '<a href="tel:+444' + t + '">' + '+444 ' + t_with_spaces + '</a>';
}
```

These functions I then call in the `body`'s `onload`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, ES2015+ onwards have [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) forw easier interpolation of string and data. For instance:

```
function fix_m_link(){
  var item1 = '@'
  var item2 = '.'
  var m_clear_text = `test${item1}example${item2}com`
  document.getElementById('m_link').innerHTML = `<a href="mailto:${m_clear_text}">${m_clear_text}</a>`
}
```

Also, JavaScript uses camel case for naming. So you might want to change `fix_m_link` and `m_clear_text`.

Putting code in one line makes it hard to read. If you have a build step, let a minifier do this. If the code is very short (like in your question), the extra kilobytes saved from omitted newlines is not worth making the code unreadable. Write code for humans to read.

Now if you *really* want to obscure your email, use a contact form instead. Some CMSes support this out of the box. And if your site is static, there are third-party services that allow you to embed a contact form. Most of them also support captchas, which will deter automated form submissions.

Answer (score 2):

### [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Thanks to [Joseph's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/222022/104270) about [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), much appreciated, and implemented.

---

### [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

[Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is used here to bypass my [Content Security Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/), as **no inline scripts** - like I had in the `body`'s `onload` - **are allowed** now.

---

### Readability - goodbye long lines

It's imperative for new script readers (and the owner too) to have a clean-looking in front of their eyes for the code to be easily maintained. Thus, an enhancement has been implemented in the form of line breaks.

---

### [Obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) (like `mail:` + `tel:` gone, hexa `char`s, etc.)

The script contains no texts as whole for crawlers to `grep` for now.

Not only the `mail:` and `tel:` are gone, split in pieces; more importantly, some key characters have been encoded into hexadecimal codes and are being converted on-the-fly.

---

### [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Regarding the camelCase, it is established in JavaScript, so I implemented it into the script.

---

### Re-written code

I was now able to tweak my script as follows:

```js
( function fixEmlLink ()
{

    var itemX = String.fromCharCode(parseInt('0x40'));
    var itemY = String.fromCharCode(parseInt('0x2e'));

    var emlClearText = `info${itemX}example${itemY}com`;

    document.getElementById('eml_link').innerHTML =
        '<a href="mai' + `lto:${emlClearText}">${emlClearText}</a>`;

} () );


( function fixPhnLink ()
{

    var itemX = String.fromCharCode(parseInt('0x37'));
    var itemY = String.fromCharCode(parseInt('0x30'));

    var phnWithSpace = `${itemX}${itemX}8 8${itemY}8 8${itemY}${itemY}`;
    var phnClearText = phnWithSpace.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    document.getElementById('phn_link').innerHTML =
        '<a href="te' + `l:+88${itemY}${phnClearText}">+88${itemY} ${phnWithSpace}</a>`;

} () );
```